# How to make the new curves hair system follow the rig? (Fur body)

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair

I'm trying to make an animated animal with fur. Having created fur through the new curves hair system, I ran into a problem that I could not make it move with the mesh. What should I do?

Converting curves to a particle system is not an option, since this action globally changes the view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell only from the screenshot. Guessing into the blue: you don't have the *Surface Deform* node in the *Geometry Nodes* modifier on the *Curves* object.

Comment: added a couple of screenshots, could you tell me which group of nodes to add

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots! The problem is the UV map. In screenshot 2, check the GN. It modifier says "Invalid surface UVs on 6914 curves". You already have the *"Deform Curves on Surface"* node but it requires a UV unwrapped model. The UV islands must not overlap.